# Ruby: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install this app on Windows 7 https://github.com/cheezy/puppies.

I am not a developer, I am just following below steps to install it:

Ruby Version `ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]` installed on Windows 7

Steps:

1. Download zip from above link
2. Inside puppies-master do bundle update and then bundle install.
3. Then rails s
4. Launch localhost:3000
5. It gave error `ruby : unsupported parameters: :order`. I fixed it by 
          changing this line

   `@puppies = Puppy.paginate :page =>params[:page], :order => 'name', :per_page => 4` to this line
   `@puppies = Puppy.order(:name).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)`
6. Error was gone and on localhost:3000 it showed me the app launched
7. But puppies (data) weren't there so I did

   `bundle && rake db:create && rake db:migrate` and then `rake db:seed`
8. Refresh the localhost page and all puppies appeared but after I am not able to complete the transaction and on hitting `Complete the adoption` button it is giving me an error.

   `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

If you just type `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` in SOF you will get so many solutions but it seems different then those, because none worked for me.

This is what log says:

```
Started GET "/orders/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-20 10:10:51
Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
  Cart Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:23:in `new'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (242.5ms)


Started GET "/orders/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-20 11:20:21 
Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
  Cart Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:23:in `new'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (252.0ms)
```

**Edit:**

**orders_controller.rb**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:new, :create]

  def index
    @orders = Order.paginate :page=>params[:page], :order=>'created_at desc',
    :per_page => 10

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
    end
  end

  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
    end
  end

  def new
    @cart = current_cart
    if current_cart.adoptions.empty?
      redirect_to agency_url, :notice => "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    @order = Order.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @order }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.add_adoptions_from_cart(current_cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        format.html { redirect_to(agency_url, :notice => 'Thank you for adopting a puppy!') }
        format.json { render :json => @order }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
        format.html { redirect_to(@order, :notice => 'Order was successfully updated.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    adoption = @order.adoptions.first
    adoption.delivered_on = Time.now
    adoption.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(orders_url, :notice => "Please thank #{@order.name} for the order!") }
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit2:**

**current_card method --**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authorize
  protect_from_forgery

  private

  def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end

  protected

  def authorize
    unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
      redirect_to login_url, :notice => "Please log in"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Update the question with `orders_controller` code

Comment: currently ur Ruby2.2.0 version is using so change it to the by goes to env variable to 2.2.4p230

Comment: @TusharPal didnt get what you are saying.

Comment: Find the `current_cart` method in your app and paste it in the question

Comment: hey you are currently using 2.2.0 in the project which is running and i think you need 2.2.4p230 where you have installed all the gems plz do that  please share method adoptions there is problem

Comment: @TusharPal I should upgrade Ruby version from `2.2.0` to `2.2.4`??

Comment: use this version rvm 1.9.3-p194

Comment: @TusharPal using version 1.9.3-p194 is giving this error `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in 'to_spec'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in 'gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rails:22:in '<main>'`